# Oracle data warehousing for creating data cubes

Tags: database, oracle, data-warehouse, oracle-olap

I have to create an Oracle data warehouse so that I can create data cubes on that database, but I don't know how to start. I have an oracle database running as a production database. Using this database I get all my production data and dump that into the data warehouse, so what i do first? like first I create a database on a server and then install a warehouse builder and then create data cubes on that?

Comment: what tool will you be using to deliver the data cubes? I also suggest you first google 'star schema'

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I will use oracle AWM for creating cubes. can I make data cubes on the transactional database?

Comment: Did you google "star schema"? You should create a star schema in the database. This is the perfect model for use by cube engines.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid this star schema can I create in transaction database?

Comment: Yes. You're getting really mixed up with terminology here. A star schema contains fact and dimension tables. Fact and dimension tables are simply normal database tables but modelled in a certain way. You create a star schema in a database, and it makes it easier to build cubes.

Comment: ok @Nick.McDermaid now i am getting closer, now tell me steps which i do first like first i understand star schema and then create cubes?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid and also tell me which tool i use to create start schema and data cubes in the oracle database.

Comment: You can create a star schema using SQL Developer. You design the star schema first then you build it in SQL Developer. But to be honest you seem a long way from that. I suggest you install AWM (the tool you already mentioned) and do some investigation. A Data warehouse does not arise from a vacumn. You must have some business requirements right? You can't just build an analytics system with tools, you need to analyse and understand it.

Comment: Maybe start here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJ122Miiavo NOTE: I am linking to youtube videos... anyone can search and find a youtube video

Comment: ok @Nick.McDermaid i will do this and let you know my progress.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes I have some business requirements and structure of star schema in my mind that will full fill the business requirement, I am confused about how to start things.i just want to do this without creating a data warehouse or a separate database for this, now I have some direction that I can do this also on my transaction database by creating a star schema and then create cube by using AWM or SQL developer right.

Comment: You don't technically need an intermediate database. It's just the way it's always done, for good reason. So if you're having difficulty starting I suggest you install AWM and start building cubes directly from your OLTP database.